# NSInternalInconsistencyException when no network connection in iOS6 on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6

Discovered a bug with iPads running iOS 6 when there's no network connection present. The app will crash with a NSInternalInconsistencyException noting a missing nib as the cause.

- I've confirmed the nib is present in the target's Build Phases >> Copy Bundle Resources
- My app doesn't require a network connection to work but uses ASI for tracking, which times out after 10 seconds
- The app works as expected on iPhones and iPads where there is a network connection
- This issue just started presenting itself with iOS 6; iOS 5 and below works as expected.

Here's the crash log for reference: http://pastebin.com/KJ3Rh5cA

Anyone seen anything like this before? Very strange bug I can't seem to figure out.

Comment: If you've found a reproducible bug, you should log it at `https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/`

Comment: It's reproducible but I'm not sure if it's apple's bad code or mine that's causing it. Will report it anyway as it's a new bug in iOS 6 that wasn't there before, but would like to learn more about why it's happening and a possible workaround.

Comment: If you're interested enough, you could use one of your Technical Support Incidents (TSI) and get some direct Apple assistance. But you'd really have to be interested in the answer to go this route.

Comment: thanks for the guidance. I filed my radar and will see how interested I end up. =)